# Having trouble with end if/overflow codes with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I try to end my if statement I get an error message "End if without block if" but every time I take out the end if I get an error message "overflow".

I have tried taking out the g=g+1 but I need that for the code to run correctly and I have tried writing the code without a loop but it is to long because I need the code to run multiple loops with different variables eventually.

```
Sub Pleasepleasework()    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim g As Integer

    Dim Media As Object
    Dim BOM As Object

    i = 4
    g = 6

    Set Media = Worksheets("Media").Cells(i, 1)
    Set BOM = Worksheets("Bill of Materials").Cells(g, 6)

    Do Until i = 17 And g = 23
        i = i + 1
        g = g + 1

        If Media.Value = 0 Then BOM.ClearContents
    Loop
End Sub
```

I want this code to run through the cells and recognize if they are zero in the first column if. If the values are zero I want it to jump of to the BOM sheet and clear the contents in row g column 6.

Comment: Okay, so if `i = 4` and `g = 6`, and you add increments of 1 to ___each simultaneously___, why do you think this statement would ever be true: `Do Until... i = 17 AND g = 23`? It's impossible

Comment: How can I make the loop stop?

Comment: Well, don't use a statement to end a loop that will never be true is a good start. Were you looking for `i = 17 OR h = 23`? (Notice the __OR__ instead of __AND__?)

Comment: @hanshultz10 By using a condition that's actually going to happen.

Comment: Sub Pleasepleasework()

Dim i As Integer
Dim g As Integer

Dim Media As Object
Dim BOM As Object

i = 4
g = 6

Set Media = Worksheets("Media").Cells(i, 1)
Set BOM = Worksheets("Bill of Materials").Cells(g, 6)

Do Until i = 17

i = i + 1
g = g + 1

If Media.Value = 0 Then BOM.ClearContents
End If

Loop

End Sub

Comment: So I changed my code to this but will only run in the first cell now?

Comment: Also, unrelated to the current convo, if you don't reset `BOM` inside your loop using that `g` variable, it will always be referencing the same cell. You are just clearing the same cell over and over and over again and it never ends since your loop ending condition never hits.

Comment: @hanshultz10 Please don't post unformatted code in the comments. Instead, use the [edit] link to edit the body of the question and add the _formatted_ code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code below is more or less what you are trying to achieve:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pleasepleasework()

Dim i As Long, g As Long
Dim MediaSht As Worksheet, BOMSht As Worksheet

' set the worksheet objects
Set MediaSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Media")
Set BOMSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bill of Materials")

g = 6
With MediaSht
    For i = 4 To 17
        If .Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
            BOMSht.Range("G" & g).ClearContents
        End If
        g = g + 1
    Next i
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed!